# Как запустить цикл foreach loop в массиве?

Tags: php

У меня в одном массиве есть ещё 3 массива, эти 3 внутренних массив должны выводиться циклом, но у меня не получается запустить цикл внутри основного массива. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать?

```html
$adresses = array(
    'Kazan' => array(
        'name' => 'Казань',
        'header_phone' => '123',
        'header_adress' => '123',
        'header_adress2' => '123',
    ),
    'belgorod' => array(
        'name' => 'Белгород',
        'header_phone' => '123',
        'header_adress' => '123',
        'header_adress2' => '123',
    ),
    'volgograd' => array(
        'name' => 'Название города_3',
        'header_phone' => '123',
        'header_adress' => '123',
        'header_adress2' => '123',
    ),
);
```

Я пытаюсь делать так, но всё крашится, так цикл не запускается:

```html
$adresses = array(
while ( have_rows( 'contacts', 'option' ) ) : the_row();
'Kazan' => array(
'name' => 'Казань',
'header_phone' => the_sub_field( 'number' );,
'header_adress' => the_sub_field( 'adr' );,
'header_adress2' => the_sub_field( 'adr2' );,
),
endwhile;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach($adresses as $adress){
    foreach($adress as $value){
        echo $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Казань
123
123
123
Белгород
123
123
123
Название города_3
123
123
123
```

Comment: Ну и конечно оформить можно как вам потребуется, с ключами и т.д.

Comment: У меня в цикле должны добавляться значений из переменных

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос с примером того, как в итоге пытаюсь получить значения. Мне нужно передать данные из цикла массивов в основной массив.

Answer (score 0):

```
$adresses = [
    'Kazan' => [
        'name' => 'Казань',
        'header_phone' => '123',
        'header_adress' => '123',
        'header_adress2' => '123',
    ],
    'belgorod' => [
        'name' => 'Белгород',
        'header_phone' => '123',
        'header_adress' => '123',
        'header_adress2' => '123',
    ],
    'volgograd' => [
        'name' => 'Название города_3',
        'header_phone' => '123',
        'header_adress' => '123',
        'header_adress2' => '123',
    ],
];

foreach ($adresses as $key => $value) {
    echo 'name          : ' . $value['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'header_phone  : ' . $value['header_phone'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'header_adress : ' . $value['header_adress'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'header_adress2: ' . $value['header_adress2'] . PHP_EOL;
    echo "---------------" . PHP_EOL;
}
/* output is
name          : Казань
header_phone  : 123
header_adress : 123
header_adress2: 123
---------------
name          : Белгород
header_phone  : 123
header_adress : 123
header_adress2: 123
---------------
name          : Название города_3
header_phone  : 123
header_adress : 123
header_adress2: 123
---------------
*/
```